# How to open fourth tab as first tab in JTabbedPane in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8, jtabbedpane

I have a tabbed pane including five tabs on it . This tabbed pane is on a `JPanel`  I use a button on another `JPanel` to get fourth tab as leading tab . But when I click on the button first tab is still display and I have to move to the fourth one manually . Have any ideas . Thanks in deep.

**Button action**

```
Center instance1 = Center.getInstance();
instance1.doClickHistoryBtn();
```

**doClickHistoryBtn() method**

```
public void doClickHistoryBtn(){
    history_btn.doClick();
}
```

When I execute this doClickHistoryBtn() method , History_panel is loading.

**second JPanel (History_panel)**

```
private JPanel history_panel1;
private JPanel history_panel2;
private JPanel history_panel3;
private JPanel history_panel4;
private JPanel history_panel5;

public History_panel()
{
    initComponents();
    setPanels();
}   

private void setPanels(){    

}
```

[image: first screen image]

This is my first screen.

**Expected**

[image: changed image]

**Actual**

[image: result image]

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: [`JTabbedPane#setSelectedIndex`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setSelectedIndex-int-) or [`JTabbedPane#setSelectedComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setSelectedComponent-java.awt.Component-)

Comment: JTabbedPane#setSelectedIndex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(3);

Above code will do it
In setSelectedIndex() method you have to pass the index of the tabbedpane you want to set as default. And it will open that pane whose index u will providing as argument to the setSelectedIndex().